# iPhone app for drawing on a screen capture video of my iPhone for my iPhone

Tags: video, video-editing, iphone-app, drawing

I am a developer. Myself and my team are responsible for an iPhone app used by our users. Our goal is to have an incredibly easy to use application. That is easier said than done.

Thus, we, on occasion need to create videos of ourselves (screen capture videos) using our app, sometimes with audio.

I know how to do that.

What I want to be able to do is to be able to draw on my video, including shapes, etc. For example, when I want to bring attention to a specific field or button in our application, I want to draw an arrow to that item, or surround the button with a green or blue oval or rectangle. I want to do that because I think visually that will help my users see the feature I am trying to point out to them -- like look at this button, or enter text in this field. I really think those kinds of visual cues can be helpful. In fact, I know they can, when members of our company or our customers do the same thing for myself and my team of developers, it really helps us.

So, I need video editing software that lets me draw arrows, shapes, boxes, ovals, on my video of my screen capture of myself using our app.

I require that the application permit me to do this on my iPhone. I have made the video on my iPhone, I am interacting with our user via the iPhone, I just want to add these finishing touches to help my user by editing the video on my iPhone and drawing on that video -- arrows, boxes, ovals, etc.

Can someone recommend an application - free or for purchase -- I can purchase it, that allows me to draw on my video on my iPhone.

Thanks!